# How to add cronjob/scheduler for Python scripts on EC2 AWS?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a question regarding one of my React apps that I recently developed. It's basically a landing page, which is using React frontend and Node+Express backend and its scraping data from various pages (scrapers are developed in Python).

Right now, the React app itself is hosted in Heroku and the execution of scrapers is working, but it's not scheduled automatically.
Current setup is the following:

- EC2 for Python scrapers
- AWS RDS MYSQL for database where I write the data to from the EC2 scrapers

I have created a separate file to execute all the others scrapers.

**main.py**

```
import time
import schedule
import os
from pathlib import Path
print('python script executed')


# make sure, what is the current working directory to add the right paths to scrapers
path = os.getcwd()
print(path)
#exec(open("/home/ec2-user/testing_python/lhvscraper.py").read())


filenames = [
    #output table: fundsdata
    Path("/home/ec2-user/testing_python/lhvscraper.py"),
    Path("/home/ec2-user/testing_python/luminorscrapertest.py"),
    Path("/home/ec2-user/testing_python/sebscraper.py"),
    Path("/home/ec2-user/testing_python/swedscraper.py"),
    Path("/home/ec2-user/testing_python/tulevascraper.py"),

    #output table: feesdata
    Path("/home/ec2-user/testing_python/feesscraper.py"),

    #output table: yield_y1_data
    Path("/home/ec2-user/testing_python/yield_1y_scraper.py"),

    #output table: navdata
    #Path("/home/ec2-user/testing_python/navscraper.py"),
]

def main_scraper_scheduler(): 
    print("scheduler is working")

    for filename in filenames:
        print(filename)
        with open(filename) as infile:
            exec(infile.read())

    time.sleep(11)

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(main_scraper_scheduler)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I have successfully established a connection between MYSQL and EC2 and tested it on Putty -
which means, if I execute my **main.py**, all of the scrapers are working, inserting new data to the MYSQL database tables, and then repeat again (see the code above). The only thing is that when I close Putty (kill the connection), then the main.py function stops running.

**So my question is**: how to set it up like that, so that main.py file would **always** keep running (let's say, once a day at 12 PM) without me executing it?

I understand it's about setting up cron job or scheduler (or smth like that), but I didn't manage to set it up right now, so yours' help is very much needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How often?  The easy way is to add your script to `/etc/cron.hourly` or `/etc/cron.daily`.  If it needs a different schedule, then it's just adding a line using `crontab -e`, but you'll need to know the format of the line.  `man crontab` can help.

Comment: @TimRoberts edited the question. Let's say once a day at 12 PM, for instance.

Comment: Can you please explain that bit a bit more: how to set up this `/etc/cron.daily` for instance? Actually that's my main question, how to set up the crontab ...

Comment: I'll add an answer to explain.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid making `crontab` files overly long, Linux has canned entries that run things hourly, daily, weekly, or monthly.  You don't have to modify any crontab to use this.  ANY executable script that is located in `/etc/cron.hourly` will automatically be run once an hour.  ANY executable script that is located in `/etc/cron.daily` will automatically be run once per day (usually at 6:30 AM), and so on.  Just make sure to include a #! line for Python, and `chmod +x` to make it executable.  Remember that it will run as `root`, and you can't necessarily predict which directory it will start in.  Make no assumptions.

The alternative is to add a line to your own personal crontab.  You can list your crontab with `crontab -l`, and you can edit it with `crontab -e`.  To run something once a day at noon, you might add:

```
0 12 * * *  /home/user/src/my_daily_script.py
```

Comment: Right okay. Just to make sure I understood it, I'm gonna explain your solutions once again.  
1. create a directory `/etc/cron.daily` (right now everything is in  `/home/ec2-user/testing_python/ `) and  move the script (in my case, it's main.py) to this directory. That's it. In case I want it to run daily.  

2. Create this command to specify the exact time (https://crontab.guru/ for time formatting). One more question about this one though - how to save & exit the crontab editor? :)  

Anyways, thanks a lot @Tim! I'll try it out.

Comment: You don't have to create `/etc/cron.daily`, those all exist already.  Go look.  You will need `sudo` to copy there.  The `crontab` command uses whatever editor is configured in the `EDITOR` environment variable. It's usually `vi`.  If you're not a `vi` guy, use `ZZ` to save and exit.

Comment: Okay, I found these directories such as `/etc/cron.daily` and all the others, lots of stuff over there :). Also thanks for the help regarding Vim. Thank you very much, really appreciate it! I'll try out both ways.

Comment: Hi @Tim. I wanted to clarify this bit: where exactly do I have to place this 
`make sure to include a #! line for Python`? Does it have to be in the Python file that I'm executing (based on your following example, `home/user/src/my_daily_script.py`?

Comment: Like: what does this `#! line for Python` have to include?

Comment: If you just run `./my_script.py`, the system has no idea how to execute it.  You need to tell it to run the Python interpreter.  You do that by adding a "shebang (`#!`) as the first line of the file.  For Python, usually, you'll just say `#! /usr/bin/env python`.